# how can activity start a new activity and close itself?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an android view which calls another view and should be closed.

I use this code

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();               
        }
```

and I see after Activity B is on and calls finish, Activity A appears

and i understand it has never been closed.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: This seems wrong to me, you have to choose between excepting a value back from the new activity, in which case you can't finish the current one, on starting the new activity without excepting a value back, in chich case you could finish the "mother" activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    A.this.finish();   
    startActivity(intent);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish()` before starting the activity

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            finish();               
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
        }
```

Comment: won't this close the activity before starting the new one?

Comment: That is what you wanted right? closing the activity! And yes it will finish the activity before starting the new one

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Intent Where you wan to Start new Activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,newActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and you have to **override** MainActivity **onPause()**

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: have to ? why onCreate/onPause?

Comment: you can finish Activity anywhere you want to, but this is the proper way to finish Activity in onPause, because when we call new activity in intent so our application come to onPause and they Pause our Activity, therefore i override this functionality by finishing first Activity

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();               
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();               
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are starting activity `B` for result from activity `A`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();               
}
```

So activity `A` is expecting result to delivered by activity `B` when activity `B` finishes.

Now, to get around this problem, start activity `B` in `onActivityResult()` method of the activity from which you started activity `A`.

```
// modified onClick method
public void onClick(View v) {
    // simply set result to OK and finish activity A
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}
```

In the activity that starts activity `A`, define two constants or you can have a separate Java class to define constants and refer them in this class.

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_FOR_A = 100;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_FOR_B = 101;
```

Override the `onActivityResult()` method in the activity that starts activity `A` and start activity `B` as follows

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FOR_A) {
            // start activity B when activity returns RESULT_OK
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FOR_B);
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FOR_B) {
            // handle the result from Activity B
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.